# How to decrease metadata disk usage of journald logs?

Tags: systemd, logging, docker

```
myuser@myhost:~$ sudo journalctl > log.txt
myuser@myhost:~$ sudo journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 3.0G on disk.
myuser@myhost:~$ ls -lh log.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 298M Oct 31 15:15 log.txt
```

So my journal is using 3G of disk space, but actual log entries is only ~300M. I imagine that journal metadata is taking rest of it.

Is it possible to change the ratio of metadata to log entries? Or maybe it's not metadata but something else?

Almost all of those logs are generated by containerized apps, `dockerd --log-driver=journald`

**Update**:

My `journald.conf`:

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
RateLimitInterval=0
RateLimitBurst=0
ForwardToSyslog=no
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what you see reported as "on disk" may not be on disk at all. As clarified in a recent [bug fix](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4059), the new language says "in the file system", which may be in an in-memory file system or disk-backed. By default in Ubuntu 16.04, it's memory-backed, but there's a [bug report to make the systemd journal persistent by default in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1618188).

Now how to reduce the space. If you're not sure to where to start to find documentation on journald, `man -k journald` is helpful to see if you have related documentation installed about it already:

```
$ man -k journald
journald.conf (5)    - Journal service configuration files
journald.conf.d (5)  - Journal service configuration files
systemd-journald (8) - Journal service
systemd-journald-audit.socket (8) - Journal service
systemd-journald-dev-log.socket (8) - Journal service
systemd-journald.service (8) - Journal service
systemd-journald.socket (8) - Journal service
```

Since you seem to be looking to tune the configuration, `man journald.conf` is a good place to check. There you'll find docs for several options related to disk space, which you can read the details about there. Here's a summary:

- `Compress=`, enabled by default, compresses the data
- `SystemMaxUse=` and `RuntimeMaxUse=` control how much disk space the journal may use up at most.
- `MaxRetentionSec=`  The maximum time to store journal entries.

See the mentioned man page for the full docs then edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

Finally `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl reload systemd-journald` to make your changes take effect.

Comment: Thx for ideas but I read man page like hundred times, I edited my question with journal conf and rephrased the title. I am converned only with metadata and all config options are related to size in general (both logs + metadata).

Comment: you cannot reload you have to restart the `systemd-journald` service